# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in Angular

Tags: angularjs, rest, google-chrome, jira-rest-api

I am using a REST API call to query all open issues in the JIRA server. Below is the query:

```
https://jiraserver/rest/api/2/search?jql=project IN ("Project Name") AND status  IN (open)
```

When I pass the query in Google Chrome advanced REST client, I am able to get a JSON response but when I give this in a HTTP call in Angular.js it returns:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header error.

I am new to Angular.js, and I am not able to recognize what is going wrong. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

#### *`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`*

This comes when the server is configured for not to share data for cross domain requests.

*When I pass the query in google chrome advanced rest client , am able to get a json response*

Yes, All the rest clients can access data because they are allowed to do so, but for `ajax` You should enable the `CORS` to share data cross domain.

#### Another way is to create proxy

What one can do is, create a proxy at server which can in turn calls the other url and get the data and send it. You can do something like this:

```
<?php 
    // suppose this page as "proxy.php"
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://jiraserver/rest/api/2/search?jql=project'));
    echo $jsonData;
?>
```

Then in the ajax you can use ajax to send a request to this file:

```
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/proxy.php'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: I have a html/angular app hosted locally in a apache tomcat server. am trying to access an rest api through a http call .  
I have done the following in tomcat web.xml                                       <filter>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
     </filter>
     <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
       <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
     </filter-mapping>                                                                                     But the same error occurs again

Answer (score -1):

Since JIRA 6.0 you could configure a whitelist for [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/), see [JIRA-30371](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-30371):

> CORS has been supported in the JIRA REST API since JIRA 6.0 for JIRA Server. If you are a JIRA Server customer, simply go to the "Whitelist" section of JIRA Administration and add the domains you wish to request resources from. **Note**: You must have the System Administrator global permission to access this section of JIRA administration.
>
> Unfortunately, this domain whitelist is not available in JIRA Cloud for security reasons. We are currently exploring alternative ways to allow certain requests that would not expose JIRA to this attack vector. I will update this issue as soon as we have more information.

See also: [Configuring the Whitelist](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jira/configuring-the-whitelist-231342130.html)